# Can "either" refer to more than two people?

Tags: grammar

"If either of you feel sick, you must report it."

Can this be said to a group of people over two persons? Or must "either" only be used when talking to/about specifically **two** persons/people?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is “either” only used with two options?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40950/is-either-only-used-with-two-options)

Answer (score 2):

*Either*, *neither*, *both*, *between*, *former*, and *latter* are all words that imply exactly two things are involved.

Comment: Goos answer. Though with between, there are other possibilities, e.g. *We have 10 dollars between the three of us.*